# PowerShell script for automated Octopus Tentacle registering fails to register new machine

Tags: powershell

I used an [official recommendation](https://octopus.com/docs/infrastructure/deployment-targets/windows-targets/automating-tentacle-installation#AutomatingTentacleinstallation-Example:ListeningTentacle) to create my automated Octopus Tentacle installation script, and the part of the interest in the script is as follows:

```
.\Tentacle.exe create-instance --instance "$hostname" --config "$home_path\Tentacle.config" --console
.\Tentacle.exe configure --instance "$hostname" --trust "$trusted_cert" --console
.\Tentacle.exe configure --instance "$hostname" --home "$home_path" --app "$home_path\Applications" --port $port --console
& netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Octopus Deploy Tentacle" dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=$port

$envs_cmd = ''
foreach ($env in $environments){
    $envs_cmd += "--environment=$env "
}
$roles_cmd = ''
foreach ($role in $roles){
    $roles_cmd += "--role='$role' "
}

.\Tentacle.exe new-certificate --instance="$hostname" --if-blank --console
    
.\Tentacle.exe register-with --instance "$hostname" --server "$server" --name="$hostname" --apiKey="$api_key" $roles_cmd $envs_cmd --server-comms-port "$port" --comms-style TentaclePassive --console --force

.\Tentacle.exe service --instance "$hostname" --install --start --console
```

Everything works except the pre-last line

```
.\Tentacle.exe register-with --instance "$hostname" --server "$server" --name="$hostname" --apiKey="$api_key" $roles_cmd $envs_cmd --server-comms-port "$port" --comms-style TentaclePassive --console --force
```

that throws the exception:

```
CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Untitled3.ps1
```

If I print this particular line to get all the variables values, and copy/paste it to PowerShell console - it works. What withdraws my attention in the line is **$roles_cmd $envs_cmd** which expression should be something like:

```
--role="Role1" --environment="Env1" --environment="Env2"
```

This is the only part of the questionable line where both parameter name and its value are the expression. Can that cause this issue? How to handle that?

Comment: Powershell is invoking the command with ``... "--role='myrole' " "-environment=myenv " ...``, not ```--role='myrole'  -environment=myenv``` - i.e. it's being helpful and wrapping the entire variable value in quotes rather than just appending it to the command verbatim. As for fixing it, I'm not sure off the top of my head, but you could use ```Start-Process``` instead...

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I also tried (with the same result):
    `$argumentList = @()
...
    foreach ($role in $roles) { $argumentList.Add('--role="'+$role+'"') }
    foreach ($env in $environments) { $argumentList.Add('--environment="'+$env+'"') }
...

    Start-Process -FilePath "Tentacle.exe" -ArgumentList $argumentList`

Answer (score 0):

I didn't manage to complete the job on this way. For anyone, if needed, the only working script at the end was:

```
$home_path     = "C:\Octopus"
$roles         = @()
$environments  = @()
$hostname      = [System.NET.DNS]::GetHostByName($null).HostName
$octopusApiKey = ''
$octopusURI    = ''
$header        = @{ "X-Octopus-ApiKey" = $octopusApiKey }
$space         = ''

function GetEnvironmentIds($environments)
{
    
    [System.Collections.ArrayList] $environmentIds = @()
    $collectedEnvironments = (Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri "$octopusURI/api/$space/environments/all" -Headers $header) | Where-Object {$environmentNames -contains $_.Name}
    foreach ($environment in $collectedEnvironments)
    {
        $environmentIds.Add($environment.Id) | Out-Null
    }
    return $environmentIds
}

cd $home_path
Add-Type -Path 'Newtonsoft.Json.dll'
Add-Type -Path 'Octopus.Client.dll'

$tentacleThumbprint = .\Tentacle.exe show-thumbprint --instance "$hostname" --nologo | Out-String -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
if ($LASTEXITCODE -ne 0)
{
    $tentacleThumbprint = .\Tentacle.exe new-certificate --instance="$hostname" --if-blank --console | Out-String
}
$endpoint = new-object Octopus.Client.OctopusServerEndpoint $octopusURI, $octopusApiKey
$repository = new-object Octopus.Client.OctopusRepository $endpoint
   
$tentacleEndpoint = New-Object Octopus.Client.Model.EndPoints.ListeningTentacleEndpointResource
$tentacleEndpoint.Thumbprint = $tentacleThumbprint 
$tentacleEndpoint.Uri = "https://"+$hostname+":10933"

$tentacle = New-Object Octopus.Client.Model.MachineResource
$tentacle.Endpoint = $tentacleEndpoint
$tentacle.Uri = "https://"+$hostname+":10933"
$environmentsIds = GetEnvironmentIds($environments)
foreach($environmentId in $environmentsIds) { $tentacle.EnvironmentIds.Add($environmentId) }
foreach($role in $roles){ $tentacle.Roles.Add($role); }
$tentacle.Thumbprint = $tentacleThumbprint
$tentacle.Name = $hostname;

$repository.Machines.Create($tentacle);
```